# kafka throwing error suddenly for one particular topic which has worked previously

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

when iam pushing data the following topic throwing the error, while the other topics are working fine. please let me know the issue.Thanks

```
 WARN Failed to send producer request with correlation id 2 to broker 1003 with data for partitions [TelematicsEvent,0] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:122)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:77)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:76)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:107)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:107)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:107)
        at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:106)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:106)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:106)
        at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:257)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:108)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
```

Comment: Does this happen repetitively with the same topic?

Comment: No, it happened for the first time since i started using it